# Google Doclist API: revisions feed: minor revisions?

Tags: google-docs-api

Is there a way to access the minor changes via the revisions feed?

Thanks

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Docs has no concept of minor and major revisions and all revisions are available via the Revisions feed. If you are referring to [*pruned* revisions](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95902), there is currently no way to retrieve the individual revisions that were pruned.

Comment: Revisions feed currently seems to merge revisions regardless of author, which makes it impossible to see who actually contributed to a document.  This is important in a range of scenarios...

Comment: Incidentally, Writely does distinguish between "detailed" (minor) vs. major revisions.  Detailed revisions are visible through the UI, and not accessible through the Revisions feed.  No idea how these correlate to spreadsheet pruned revisions; presumably they are not pruned or the UI couldn't see them?